# Pycharm lost collectstatic task of Django manage.py

Tags: django, pycharm

env:

- Pycharm 2.7.3
- Django 1.4.5
- Python 2.7.5
- Windows 7 32bit

Just like the pic show below, Pycharm lost the collectstatic task of manage.py script of Django project, it seems I have not do something strange.
[image]
But another project is normal:

[image]
What is the matter?

My project settings.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Django settings for bae_django2 project.
import os

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS
if 'SERVER_SOFTWARE' in os.environ:
    from bae.core import const
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': 'NNYUsjawDsfjFCtObVqU',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            'USER': const.MYSQL_USER,                      # Not used with sqlite3.
            'PASSWORD': const.MYSQL_PASS,                  # Not used with sqlite3.
            'HOST': const.MYSQL_HOST,                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
            'PORT': const.MYSQL_PORT,                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default':{
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': 'NNYUsjawDsfjFCtObVqU',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
            'PASSWORD': '123456',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
            'PORT': '3306',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        }
    }

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Site root, add by Honghe
SITE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
# STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static').replace('\\','/')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static').replace('\\','/'),
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'tobvndv#nd-q9yf(igo7xh&amp;@i3_hqm^rh_xwoujte@pjmo#*8w'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'bae_django2.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'bae_django2.wsgi.application'

import os
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates').replace('\\','/'),)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'hello',
    'books',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the versions of django the same in both projects?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes. All Django 1.4. It is OK just now.

Comment: Have you tried to contact pycharm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably caused by some change in the `settings.py` file. The only possible way that I can fathom could have caused this, is if there was a change in the `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple. Please compare your the tuple in your project and your new project and see if there are any changes in the django apps installed. That is all I can tell you since, I cannot see your `settings.py` file.

Comment: Thx! Have pasted the settings.py above.

Comment: Okay change `STATIC_ROOT` to `''`. That should do the trick. You do not need to change `STATIC_ROOT` for collect-static anyways, since you already seem to have it as your default `static` storage folder.

Comment: Not the reason. Maybe it is the problem of Pycharm, I create a new project and copy files to it, `collectstatic` comes back.